# Changing the output results of Parser in Powershell

Tags: performance, function, powershell, parsing

So I have a parser that goes through two different logs, both .csv files, and checks for certain lines based off the regex code that I have chosen.

This one grabs the IDNumber from the beginning of the filename(1234-randomfile.csv), then adds the files location to a variable($Validate), then based on the regex, adds files to certain variables($Scriptdone, $Updatedone, $Failed) and starts the checks to see if they have them.

I am trying to make it so that the output is not line for line as the files I parse through have the same IDNumbers. So for example:

Output Currently:

```
1234 Script Completed
1234 Update Completed
```

How I want output:

```
1234 Script Completed Update Completed
```

Anyways, Thanks for all the assistance!

```
function Get-MR4RES {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Position = 0,
        Mandatory = $True)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript( {Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'Any'})]
    [String]
    $Files,

    [Parameter(Position = 1,
        Mandatory = $false)]
    [String]
    $CSVPath) # End Param

begin {

    # Setting Global Variables
    $Scriptcompletedsuccess = '.+Script\scompleted\ssuccessfully.+' # 3:44:15 End function called, Script completed successfully at  3:44:15 on Tue 07/03/2018
    $Updatecomplete = '\w+\s+\:\s\[\d+\:\d+\:\d+\]\s+\w+\scomplete' # STATUS  : [03:43:07]   Update complete
    $FailedValidaton = '.+check\sfail.+'
    $Fail1 = 'Validation Failed'
    $Fail2 = 'Failed'
    $Good1 = 'Script completed'
    $Good2 = 'Update completed'
    $array = @('IDNumber, Results')
    $counter = 0
    $FileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Files -File -Filter "*.log").FullName
    $Done = ''

} # End begin

process {

    # Do the following code in all the files in the filelist
    foreach ($File in $fileList) {

        # Test files variables to ensure is directory to ensure progress bar will be operational and needed
        if ((Get-Item $Files) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {

            # Counts once per each file variable in filelist variable
            $counter++

            # Progress bar indicates the name of the current file and calculates percent based on current count verses total files in $filelist
            Write-Progress -Activity 'Analyzing Files' -CurrentOperation $File -PercentComplete (($counter / $FileList.count) * 100)

        }

        # Calculates ID number based on filename, file name is -filtered in beginning to only contain properly named files
        $IDNumber = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$File").split('-')[0]

        # Puts file into Variable to be IF Else
        $Validate = Get-Content -Path $File

        $Scriptdone = $Validate | Where-Object {$_ -match $Scriptcompletedsuccess}
        $Updatedone = $Validate | where-object {$_ -match $Updatecomplete}
        $Failed = $Validate | Where-Object {$_ -match $FailedValidaton}

        # Check if the file HAS a FAILED validation
        if($Failed){

            # Creates an array of the data from each file that failed
            $array += -join ("$IDNumber",', ',"$Fail1")
        }
        Elseif($Scriptdone){
            $Done = $Good1

            # Creates an array of the data from each file that script completed
            $array += -join ("$IDNumber",', ',"$Done")

        } # if the parser found "Update complete"
        Elseif($Updatedone){
            $Done = $Good2

            # Creates an array of the data from each file that update is done
            $array += -join ("$IDNumber",', ',"$Done")

        } # End of Successful
        Else{
            # Creates an array of the data from each file that failed
            $array += -join ("$IDNumber",', ',"$Fail2")
        }

    } # End of foreach

} # End process section

End {

    # If CSVPath is used in get-command 
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('CSVPath')) {

        # Pipe the array data to a CSV
        Add-Content -Path $CSVPath -Value $array -Encoding ascii

    }

    # If no CSVPath is used in get-command
    else {

        # Out-put to console
        Write-Output $array

    } # End of else

} # End of the End

} # End of function
```

Comment: To have your working code reviewed, use [codereview.se]

Comment: @LotPings Oh, okay thanks!

Comment: @LotPings I have changed the title and modified the request, is that better?

Comment: Instead of appending immediately to `$array +=` gather output and append only once. BTW clearing the $Done variable just before setting new content into makes no sense to me. Wouldn't the use of a switch command make the structure simpler?

Comment: @LotPings hmm could you show me an example of what you mean by only appending once? Also, I have removed the excess clearing of variable $Done as I was just doing it as a precaution. Seems to run just fine without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append new message to existing output you have to tell PowerShell to which entry it should add new info. As manipulating strings is not very intuitive in my opinion I'd suggest to use an object for that.

First you have to define data structure:

```
// Before ForEach
$array = @()
$properties = @{'ID'="";
            'Results'=""}
// In ForEach
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
$object.ID = $IDNumber
```

Next, in your `if` you can set the value (this can also be done using `Switch` as suggested by [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) but let's leave it as it is for simplicity):

```
$object.Results = $Done // or $Fail or $Fail2
```

Then you should first check if the entry with such `$ID` already exists and if yes, add new result. If no, just add new element to the array. Something like this should work:

```
$line = $array | Where-Object ID -eq $object.id
if ($line) {
  $line.Results += " $($object.Results)"
}
else {
  $array += $object
}
```

Of course this will also require changing the way as you output you data (for example by using `Export-Csv`):

```
$array | Export-Csv $CSVPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
```